# How to call a Request function from a controller to another controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to call a Request function from a controller to another controller in Laravel

**Controller1.php**

```
public function get(){

$call = new Controller2();

$input = new Request();
$input->param1 = param1;
$input->param2 = param2;

$response = $call->index($input)

}
```

**Controller2.php**

```
public function Index(Request $request){
dd($request->all());
}
```

I am getting `[]` as response.

Comment: Hi, why do you want to call another controller from your current controller? You should move your logic from the Controller2 to a service or something, or use queued jobs to execute some logic.

Comment: you could use the `merge` method of Request to merge in new inputs ... but as stated already, it most often is not a good idea to call a controller from another controller, usually an architectural issue

Answer (score 0):

in the symphony request class:

```
/**
     * Retrieve an input item from the request.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $key
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function input($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return data_get(
            $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all(), $key, $default
        );
    }
```

you cannot get those variables by just calling `->input()`

I recommend to not use the Request Object for these purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new inputs and forward your first request  to second if you want

```
public function get(){
   $request->merge(['param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2, 'newParam' => $newParam]);
   $call = new Controller2($request);
   $response = $call->index($input)
}
```

So you will have access all request variables in first request, then merged two parameters then added a new one.

In your final Controller2 you will have the same request from 1 forwarded to second one.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous answer and multiple comments, this is a bad idea and indicates an architectural problem with the application.